# Cannot Put URLs into a List (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to extract all the urls in a wedpage and put all of these urls into a list. However, when I run the codes, it shows an error message as: `"tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag, and throws an exception if it's not there."` I am wondering how I can solve this issue.
My codes are as below:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
openedUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(r)

soup = BeautifulSoup(openedUrl, 'lxml')

aa = soup.find_all('a')
href = []
for a in aa:
    href.append(a['href'])

print(href)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some 'a' tags don't have a 'href' attribute, so python throws a `KeyError` exception when you try to access `a['href']`.

You can avoid that if you set the keyword argument `href` to `True`.

```
aa = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

When accessing keys from the tag attributes it's best to use the `get` method, as it returns `None` if the key does not exist and so it  won't raise an exception.